# How to type Ascii characters with more than 3 numbers?

Tags: windows, unicode, character, decimal, ascii

Is there any way to type ASCII characters with more than 3 numbers using the numpad?

For example, if I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type in <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> it prints out `¢`.

How can I type in numbers like this: `195 128`?

According to [this table](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024&names=-&utf8=dec&unicodeinhtml=dec), it have to be `À`.

But if I type in `195 128`, I get the number `8`.

What's wrong?

Comment: There are no ASCII characters whose codes are more than 3 digits long. ASCII is a 7-bit character encoding, with values from 0 to 127. Your question is specific to Windows, and it's not a programming question.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what [that table](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024&names=-&utf8=dec&unicodeinhtml=dec) is showing you. It is NOT showing you ALT codes.  It is showing you byte values.  `195 128` is the byte sequence `0xC3 0x80`, which is the UTF-8 encoded form of `À`.  ALT codes have nothing to do with UTFs, and vice versa.

Comment: Related: [Full description of Windows `Alt`+`x` codes](http://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602).

Answer (score 1):

Windows ALT key entry only supports the ANSI and OEM code pages of the localized version of Windows you are using.

For US Windows (`xxx` denotes a decimal value from 0-255):

- ALT-0xxx = code page 1252 ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437))
- ALT-xxx =  code page 437 ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252))

So ALT-0253 should give `ý` and ALT-253 should give `²`.

The character you want (`À`) exists in cp1252 and is ALT-0192.

If you type a number >255, the character displayed is modulo 256.  For ALT-445 you should get the same value as ALT-189.  I do not get `¢` so you probably have a different localized version of Windows.  [Code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) is the Western European OEM code page and would generate the character for ALT-189.  Try ALT-183 for `À`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type Alt+0192 for À.

Here is a useful link with correct alt codes: https://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/accents-alt-codes.php